# mysql compare user value to one in database but show another value same row

Tags: mysql

I am building a web site which has a database, when a customer selects a product it is checked against the database

what am trying to achieve is if the products match say a book and this is in the database is to show another another value

in my table i have `id, name, description, shipping and product_file`

```
$query = " SELECT product_file ";
$query .= " FROM products "; 
$query .= " WHERE name = '{$product_selected}' "; this value been passed into 
$query .= " LIMIT 1";
```

for my query am trying to compare the name the users inputs to the one in the database if match I want to be able

to use the value in the same row but use the value in column product_file

so far all I get as an output is the value in the column name and not the intended product_file

can help me with the query that will allow me to output the value from product_file when the values match of the name in the database and the name the user inputs

Answer (score 0):

Your where condition is filtering results on product_selected, and your SELECT is on product_file not on the column name.

Based on the information you have given it looks like this query should give you what you are asking for.

Comment: thanks for the reply you was right turned out was some previous code thanks for taking the time to answer